# How to reproduce visual division of pages with Gtk.TextView

Tags: python, gtk, pygobject, gtk4

I'm working on a text editing application, initially aimed at serving literary writers. I'm using Gtk4, Python and Flatpak and I'm having some difficulties implementing things the way I want. So I have a few questions:

1 - I know that it is possible to display the same **Gtk.TextBuffer** in several **Gtk.TextViews**, would it be possible to link a **Gtk.TextView** to a subset of the content of a TextBuffer?

2 - Would it be possible to disable the built-in vertical Scrollbar of a **Gtk.TextView** and give it a fixed size? Something like an editable **Gtk.Inscription**?

What I'm trying to reproduce is the visual division of pages. Creating each page as a **Gtk.TextView** with its own **Gtk.TextBuffer** seems to make it difficult to maintain text flow control between one page and another.

Comment: That sounds way too complicated.   Why not put some sort of separator in the text view?

Comment: Or since the user can probably only view at most 2-4 pages at a time, just load the textviews with the appropriate data from the text.  This also helps with resources because you are not loading the entire text into a textview.  This is a "windowed" view.

Comment: I'm thinking about putting a division in the TextView, but it would be complicated to control the text so that it doesn't stay under the division.

I believe that, to do it right, I would have to code my own version of a TextView that was able to page. That's what they told me in gnome discourse.